# Subclassing NSPopUpButton to add a bindable property

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, binding, nsbutton, nspopupbutton

I'm trying to add a bindable property to a custom NSPopUpButton subclass.

I've created a "selectedKey" property, which is meant to store a NSString associated with selected menu item.

In control init, I set self as button target and an action for the button (valueChanged:), which in turn sets "selectedKey" in accordance with user selection:

```
@interface MyPopUpButton : NSPopUpButton {
    NSMutableDictionary *_items;
    NSString *_selectedKey;    
}

@property(nonatomic, readwrite, copy) NSString* selectedKey;
- (void)addItemWithTitle:(NSString *)title andKey:(NSString *)key;

@end

@implementation MyPopUpButton
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frameRect {

    self = [super initWithFrame:frameRect];
    if (self) {

        _items = [NSMutableDictionary new];
        [NSObject exposeBinding:@"selectedKey"];
        [super setTarget:self];
        [super setAction:@selector(valueChanged:)];

    }
    return self;

}

- (void)addItemWithTitle:(NSString *)title andKey:(NSString *)key {

    [super addItemWithTitle:title];
    [_items setValue:title forKey:key];

}

- (void)valueChanged:(id)sender {

    for (NSString *aKey in [_items allKeys]) {
        if ([[_items valueForKey:aKey] isEqualToString:[self titleOfSelectedItem]]) {
            self.selectedKey = aKey;
        }
    }

}

- (void)setSelectedKey:(NSString *)selectedKey {

    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"selectedKey"];
    _selectedKey = selectedKey;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"selectedKey"];

    [self selectItemWithTitle:[_items valueForKey:selectedKey]];

}
@end
```

This seems to work as expected: "selectedKey" property is changed when user changes PopUpButton selection.

Unfortunately, trying to bind this property, doesn't work.

```
[selectButton bind:@"selectedKey" toObject:savingDictionary withKeyPath:key options:@{NSContinuouslyUpdatesValueBindingOption : @YES }]
```

When selection is changed bind object is not updated accordingly.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What kind of object is ``selectButton``?

Comment: @PaulPatterson `selectButton` is a `MyPopUpButton` instance. It is created at runtime (not in IB) and populated using my own `- (void)addItemWithTitle:(NSString *)title andKey:(NSString *)key` method, in order to populate both its menu items and its `_items` dictionary.

Comment: Side-stepping your question: there shouldn't be a need for a custom binding. The existing bindings give you a lot of flexibility. You can bind Content, Content Values, and Content Objects to separate-but-related things. Content would be the base objects, Values would be a key path within those objects for what to display, and Objects would also be a key path within the Content elements for what to return as the pop-up's `objectValue`. Content Objects also governs what the Selected Object binding maps to.

Comment: @KenThomases I've often used standard binding for NSPopUpButton (e.g. selected Value or selected Tag), but I'm currently working on a rather complex project that involves on the fly creation of a set of NSPopUpButtons that are used to select a custom NSString that is not what is show as item title for them. This is the reason behind my (possibly wrong) approach.

Comment: Separating the value shown as the item title from the object represented by that item is precisely the reason for the separation of the Content, Content Values, and Content Objects bindings. They should support what you've described.

Answer (score 0):

**I've created a "selectedKey" property, which is meant to store an NSString associated with selected menu item.**

Bindings is definitely the way to go here, but your use of `bind:toObject:withKeyPath:options` is incorrect.

The value that you pass to the first argument must be one of the predefined values made available by Apple for that particular control. For `NSPopUpButton` objects, the available values are documented in the [NSPopUpButton Bindings Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CocoaBindingsRef/BindingsText/NSPopUpButton.html). When you look through this document you'll see that there is no `selectedKey` option. There is however a `selectedValue` which has the following description:

*An NSString that specifies the title of the selected item in the NSPopUpButton.*

Thus the correct way to set up the binding is as follows:

```
[self.btn bind:@"selectedValue"
      toObject:self
   withKeyPath:@"mySelectedString"
       options:nil];
```

This is all you need to do: when the *action* selector is fired the property stored at the *keyPath* you passed in as the third argument will already have been updated. This means that you can (i) get rid of the `setSelectedKey` method entirely, (ii) remove `exposeBinding` line, and (iii) remove the code within `valueChanged:` - Cocoa has already done this bit.

The example below implements just two methods, but, if I've understood your intentions, they should be all you need:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    self.btn.target = self;
    self.btn.action = @selector(popUpActivity:);

    [self.btn bind:@"selectedValue"
          toObject:self
       withKeyPath:@"mySelectedString"
           options:nil];

    // I've added a couple of additional bindings here; they're
    // not required, but I thought they'd be instructive.
    [self.btn bind:@"content"
          toObject:self
       withKeyPath:@"myItems"
           options:nil];

    [self.btn bind:@"selectedIndex"
          toObject:self
       withKeyPath:@"mySelectedIndex"
           options:nil];

    // Now that you've set the bindings up, use them!
    self.myItems = @[@"Snow", @"Falling", @"On", @"Cedars"];
    self.mySelectedIndex = @3; // "Cedars" will be selected on startup
    // no need to set value of mySelectedString, because it will be
    // updated automatically by the selectedIndex binding.
    NSLog("%@", self.mySelectedString) // -> "Cedars"

}

- (void)popUpActivity:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"value of <selectedIndex> -> %@", self.mySelectedIndex);
    NSLog(@"value of <selectedString> -> %@", self.mySelectedString);
}
```

---

A final point worth making is that none of the above should be a part of an `NSPopUpButton` subclass. It looks like you can - and therefore should - do everything you need to do *without* a custom subclass of this control. In my demo-app the code above belongs to the `ViewController` class, you should try doing this also.

Comment: You are not necessarily restricted to only using the predefined bindings when calling `-bind:...`. You can override that method to add support for custom bindings (calling through to `super` for anything else), but then you have to implement the whole shebang. You would key-value observe the object for the key path and handle changes in `-observeValueForKeyPath:...`. That's described in [Cocoa Bindings Programming Topics: How Do Bindings Work?](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/Concepts/HowDoBindingsWork.html)

Comment: Yikes! Sorry, didn't realize this. I'll update my answer to reflect this, with reference to your comment.

Comment: @PaulPatterson AFAIK every property which is KVO and KVC complaint can be used in bindings. See my comment on question above about the reason behind my approach.

Comment: Yes, sorry, this was an error on my part. I wasn't aware that this was possible until Ken pointed it out yesterday. It sounds useful, and I'll be sure to look into it myself at some point.